# Creating a new variable using other variables in an expression in a multiindexed Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index, assign

I have the following multi-indexed Pandas dataframe:

```
toy.to_json()
'{"["ISRG","Price"]":{"2004-12-31":10.35,"2005-01-28":10.35,"2005-03-31":14.15,"2005-04-01":14.15,"2005-04-29":14.15,"2005-06-30":15.51,"2005-07-01":15.51,"2005-07-29":15.51,"2005-09-30":20.77,"2005-10-28":20.77},"["ISRG","Price_high"]":{"2004-12-31":13.34,"2005-01-28":13.34,"2005-03-31":16.27,"2005-04-01":16.27,"2005-04-29":16.27,"2005-06-30":17.35,"2005-07-01":17.35,"2005-07-29":17.35,"2005-09-30":25.96,"2005-10-28":25.96},"["ISRG","Price_low"]":{"2004-12-31":7.36,"2005-01-28":7.36,"2005-03-31":12.03,"2005-04-01":12.03,"2005-04-29":12.03,"2005-06-30":13.67,"2005-07-01":13.67,"2005-07-29":13.67,"2005-09-30":15.58,"2005-10-28":15.58},"["EW","Price"]":{"2004-12-31":9.36,"2005-01-28":9.36,"2005-03-31":10.47,"2005-04-01":10.47,"2005-04-29":10.47,"2005-06-30":11.07,"2005-07-01":11.07,"2005-07-29":11.07,"2005-09-30":10.86,"2005-10-28":10.86},"["EW","Price_high"]":{"2004-12-31":10.56,"2005-01-28":10.56,"2005-03-31":11.07,"2005-04-01":11.07,"2005-04-29":11.07,"2005-06-30":11.69,"2005-07-01":11.69,"2005-07-29":11.69,"2005-09-30":11.56,"2005-10-28":11.56},"["EW","Price_low"]":{"2004-12-31":8.15,"2005-01-28":8.15,"2005-03-31":9.87,"2005-04-01":9.87,"2005-04-29":9.87,"2005-06-30":10.46,"2005-07-01":10.46,"2005-07-29":10.46,"2005-09-30":10.16,"2005-10-28":10.16},"["volatility",""]":{"2004-12-31":null,"2005-01-28":null,"2005-03-31":null,"2005-04-01":null,"2005-04-29":null,"2005-06-30":null,"2005-07-01":null,"2005-07-29":null,"2005-09-30":null,"2005-10-28":null}}'
```

[image]

I want with one line of code to create a new column called 'volatility' in the second level (i.e. under both 'ISGR' and 'EW') which will be defined by the following expression:

```
(100 * (Price_high - Price_low)/Price).round()
```

I have two problems:
a) I can not create the new column
b) I can not assign it

Here is the code I used to create the column but it fails:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

100 *( toy.loc[:, idx[:, 'Price_high']]  - toy.loc[:, idx[:, 'Price_low']].div(toy.loc[:, idx[:, 'Price']])).round()
```

This code line returns NaNs:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For output `MultiIndex DataFrame` is necessary same `MultiIndex` in selected DataFrames, so use `rename`:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice

Price_high =  toy.loc[:, idx[:, 'Price_high']].rename(columns={'Price_high':'new'})
Price_low = toy.loc[:, idx[:, 'Price_low']].rename(columns={'Price_low':'new'})
Price = toy.loc[:, idx[:, 'Price']].rename(columns={'Price':'new'})
df4 = (100 * (Price_high - Price_low)/Price).round()
print (df4)
            ISRG    EW
             new   new
2004-12-31  58.0  26.0
2005-01-28  58.0  26.0
2005-03-31  30.0  11.0
2005-04-01  30.0  11.0
2005-04-29  30.0  11.0
2005-06-30  24.0  11.0
2005-07-01  24.0  11.0
2005-07-29  24.0  11.0
2005-09-30  50.0  13.0
2005-10-28  50.0  13.0
```

Another approach is use [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) for avoid second level, so  working with no `MultiIndex DataFrames`:

```
Price_high =  toy.xs('Price_high', axis=1, level=1)
Price_low = toy.xs('Price_low', axis=1, level=1)
Price = toy.xs('Price', axis=1, level=1)
df4 = (100 * (Price_high - Price_low)/Price).round()
print (df4)
            ISRG    EW
2004-12-31  58.0  26.0
2005-01-28  58.0  26.0
2005-03-31  30.0  11.0
2005-04-01  30.0  11.0
2005-04-29  30.0  11.0
2005-06-30  24.0  11.0
2005-07-01  24.0  11.0
2005-07-29  24.0  11.0
2005-09-30  50.0  13.0
2005-10-28  50.0  13.0
```

And then if need `MultiIndex` add [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
df4.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df4.columns, ['new']])
print (df4)
            ISRG    EW
             new   new
2004-12-31  58.0  26.0
2005-01-28  58.0  26.0
2005-03-31  30.0  11.0
2005-04-01  30.0  11.0
2005-04-29  30.0  11.0
2005-06-30  24.0  11.0
2005-07-01  24.0  11.0
2005-07-29  24.0  11.0
2005-09-30  50.0  13.0
2005-10-28  50.0  13.0
```